# Assembly Language - Multiplying

Tags: assembly, x86

I have created variables:

```
Y sword 8
Z sword 20
T sword 68
B sword ?
```

And I have to evaluate the following, B = 4T - (8 + Z) + Y

I am really not familiar with how to do this. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: What CPU are you writing the code for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm just trying to do this on a 32 bit computer using Visual Studio.

Comment: Then you are targeting x86 most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the swords are signed 16-bit numbers:

```
movsx eax,sword ptr T
movsx ebx,sword ptr Y
shl eax,2            ; faster than imul
movsx edx,sword Z
add eax,ebx
add edx,8
sub eax,edx
mov sword ptr B,ax
```

Then optimize a little:

```
movsx eax,sword ptr T
movsx ebx,sword ptr Y
movsx edx,sword Z
lea eax,[ebx+eax*4]   ; less code than shr
add edx,8
sub eax,edx
mov sword ptr B,ax
```

Comment: I really do not understand what you did. I am new to Assembly language and just starting to learn it. I was given an assignment to do these calculations:

A = Z - Y + T
B = 4T - (8 + Z) + Y
C1 = 4(T-8) + Z + Y
D = mod(T,8)
E = Y^2 + Z

Comment: @SameerAnand: Stack Overflow is not good place to start learning.

Comment: I translated the expression you gave in your question into the x86 assembly instructions that a (poor) compiler would generate when compiling it. Visual C++ can generate assembler for you, but you should probably read up on assembly language first if this is your first foray.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to accomplish this while *still* learning the important concepts of assembly is to write the program in C/C++ and have your compiler output the assembly.  From there, study the syntax and see if any of it starts making sense.  This is actually the way I learned x86 assembly...